# How many flips are needed to confirm a coin's intentional bias?

Tags: statistical-power, dice

I've made some 'special' coins and I know for a fact that they have a very small but known/designed bias $\epsilon$.  I define bias as the probability $(\frac{1}{2} + \epsilon)$ towards heads and $(\frac{1}{2} - \epsilon)$ for tails.    If someone were to test them, how many flips would they have to perform in order to measure $\epsilon$ with 95% confidence.

I know the exact bias (somehow), and expect the other party to measure it themselves and tell it back to me.  The testing party has unlimited resources. $\epsilon$ is of the order of $2^{-64}$.

Comment: 1. What exactly do you mean by the "bias" being $\epsilon$ exactly? A die has six sides, what population parameter(s) is this bias in relation to?  2. Given that the house edge is much larger that $\epsilon$, what use would a die with an extremely small bias be?

Comment: @Glen_b I've defined bias in the edit. You've guessed that it's not a casino question.  It's just easier phrased that way.  I expect the number of rolls to be very very large, but would appreciate it quantifying :-)

Comment: 1. If it's some other situation that doesn't involve six sides, I'd suggest using a model that comes closer to the actual circumstance. 2. Your definition is insufficient haven't yet explained how the deficit of $-\epsilon$ associated with the other 5 sides is disposed (this is not idle nitpicking; what alternative we're trying to detect affects probability of detection with some tests). If you only care about that $+\epsilon$ face (vs not-that-face) then a (possibly) biased die would be a more suitable model to discuss.

Comment: @Glen_b Good comment, and you've caught me out.  Is it easier with coins then?

Comment: Only in the sense that there's fewer things to specify, so it's clear what specific situation under the alternative we're dealing with.

Comment: @Bruce How did you come up with that?  Isn't it the case that $1/4\times (2^{-64})^{-2} = 2^{126}$ tosses are needed to achieve a standard error of $2^{-64}?$

Comment: @whuber, Thanks. I was trying for ME (half width of CI) not SE, but was still way off. Deleting comment. Basic idea that it will take a **lot** tosses still stands.

Comment: @BruceET I appreciate that it will be a lot of tosses.  But, there are mathematical disciplines where numbers on these scales are very common, even up to $2^{4096}$ and higher. I chose this forum for a statistical perspective on the answer.

Comment: @whuber Is your $2^{126}$ answer based on the $\frac{Z^2}{4 \Delta^2}$ formula from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checking_whether_a_coin_is_fair#Estimator_of_true_probability)? And can I just set $Z=2$?

Comment: For a 95% CI of the form $\hat p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n}},$ 'Z' of the link is 1.96. So you'll be close using 2 instead. Then the formula is just $1/\Delta^2.$ In public opinion polling a result like $53\% \pm 2\%$ can result from polling $n = 2500$ subjects. $1/.02^2 = 2500.$

Comment: Paul, it's a basic standard error formula.  The variance of a single flip is (essentially) $1/4,$ whence the variance of $n$ flips is $1/(4n).$ Solving for $1/(4n)=(2^{-64})^2$ gives $n.$

Comment: The term '95% confidence' doesn't mean what you imply it means in the question. It has a very specific meaning in statistics, which doesn't accord with the sense in which you are using it. It arises in frequentist approaches but you appear to be implying a sort of Bayesian sense there (either approach would be fine but the misuse of the term may lead to confusion)

Comment: Presumably the casino is trying to figure out if the coin is inconsistent with a fair coin. (Though in practice a real casino would simply never trust a coin supplied by a player because of the financial incentive to cheat.) - is the aim simply to decide if the coin is biased toward heads  specifically, or is it to detect if  it's biased in either direction or is it important that they have a certain accuracy in an estimate of $\epsilon$?

Comment: @Glen_b It's not really a casino question as you suspect. This is the only forum open to me at this time.  It's not an 'is this a fair coin' question. The aim is for the 'casino' or other party to measure $\epsilon$.  They **have** to measure it with confidence in order to use it later. I'm trying to find out (numerically) how hard it would be to measure my predetermined $\epsilon$. I would like the tosses for 95% confidence that it's $2^{-64}$ please.

Comment: Again, you're using "confidence" in a way different from its statistical sense. Can you explain what properties you need for this estimate of $\epsilon$? E.g. we could construct a confidence interval for it (or indeed a Bayesian interval), but then to get a sample size we would need some idea *how wide* an interval would be permissible-- the narrower the interval, the larger the sample size. [We also need the coverage of the interval, but you mentioned 95%, so I presume that's what you want].

Comment: e.g. if you want a two-sided interval for $\epsilon$ with lower limit no more than half-way to  0 (i.e. that goes from $\hat\epsilon/2$ to $3\hat\epsilon/2$), this would require 4 times as many observations as an interval that went from just above $0$ to $2\hat\epsilon$

Answer (score 2):

It now sounds like you're after a sample size based on the width of a confidence interval of coverage $1-\alpha$. For a two sided interval of half-width $h$ (that is, the interval will be of the form ($\hat\epsilon-h,\hat\epsilon+h)$), the required sample size is:

$n \geq Z_{α/2}^2 ­\pi(1-\pi) /h^2$

where $\pi$ is the population proportion (for small $\epsilon$ relative to $\pi$ it won't matter whether you use $\pi$ or $\pi+\epsilon$).

If $\alpha$ is 0.05 (coverage 95%) the Z value is 1.96; this is often approximated by 2.

So if $\pi$ is $\frac12$ this is about $1/h^2$. If $\pi$ is even roughly in the ballpark of $\frac12$ this doesn't change much, but if it's getting close to 0 or 1, you will get smaller $n$.

If you want a one-sided interval (you care only about a lower bound on $\epsilon$, say) then the sample size reduces a little.

Hopefully this addresses your needs; strictly I should have continued asking questions to make sure I was answering the right question but this may be useful either way.

---

If you instead need a test with a given *power* to pick up a difference of $\epsilon$ that's a different calculation (though related).